# Using java2d user space measurements with TextLayout and LineBreakMeasurer

Tags: java, layout, java-2d, line-breaks

I have a java2d image defined in user space (mm) to print an identity card. The transformation to pixels is by using an AffineTransform for the required DPI (Screen or print).

I want to wrap text across several lines but the the TextLayout does not respect user space co-ordinates. I was using the following to write wrapped text to a region:

```
private void drawParagraph(Graphics2D g2d, Rectangle2D area, String text) {
    LineBreakMeasurer lineMeasurer;
    AttributedString string = new AttributedString(text);
    AttributedCharacterIterator paragraph = string.getIterator();
    int paragraphStart = paragraph.getBeginIndex();
    int paragraphEnd = paragraph.getEndIndex();
    FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
    lineMeasurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(paragraph, frc);

    float breakWidth = (float)area.getWidth();
    float drawPosY = (float)area.getY();
    float drawPosX = (float)area.getX();
    lineMeasurer.setPosition(paragraphStart);
    while (lineMeasurer.getPosition() < paragraphEnd) {
        TextLayout layout = lineMeasurer.nextLayout(breakWidth);

        drawPosY += layout.getAscent();
        layout.draw(g2d, drawPosX, drawPosY);

        drawPosY += layout.getDescent() + layout.getLeading();
    }        
}
```

The above code determines font metrics using user space sizing of the Font and thus turn out rather large. The font size is calculated as best vertical fit for the number of lines in an area with the calculation as below. E.g.

```
attr.put(TextAttribute.SIZE, (geTextArea().getHeight() / noOfLines - LINE_SPACING) );
```

When using g2d.drawString("Some text to display", x, y) the font size appears correct.

Does anyone have a better way of doing text layout in user space co-ords?

Comment: Where are you setting attributes on the TextLayout? That's the most important step, and it's not shown here.

Comment: I'm not sure you can set any attributes as it is created using the LineBreakMeasurer (while loop). The java docs for LineBreakMeasurer say that it does not do translation to user space co-ords.

The code above is text book stuff from Sun's tutorial code. I was wondering if anyone is aware of another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

A call to `g2d.scale()` at the beginning should do it (it worked when I did it, and my code is based on the exact same `LineBreakMeasurer` example).